# How to prevent field from updating on edit? CosmosDB SQL API and .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

There are fields which are populated when a document is created but should not be updated when the document is edited (such as DateTime for when the document was created and who created it).

It looks like with LINQ and SQL, you can set the field as "isModified = false" to prevent the value from being updated, but I am unsure how to achieve the same for Cosmos DB.

Would the potential code go here in the controller?

```
public async Task<ActionResult> EditAsync(CCR report)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            await _reportService.UpdateItemAsync(report.Id, report);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(report);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was overthinking this, but I figured that setting the input to hidden and not providing a value allowed me to retain the original value

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="field" class="form-control" />
```